# Lego filling boxes with random lego to meet law requirements

Tags: sets, lego-group

In some countries, there is a law that toy boxes need to filled with at least a fixed percentage of the total volume of the box.
I know Lego addresses this by adding random Lego.
At least, I've been assured this during a Lego seminar by a Lego employee (probably community manager) at one of the fanweekend events (Paredes de Coura or Skaerbaek).

However, does anyone have a reference for this, perhaps pictures of what random Lego is added?

Comment: You mean random bricks as addition to existing elements needed for a set? That's an odd thing to hear. From my point of view, reducing the size of the box helps dealing with such law (which I never heard of too). And I think this has already happened with some sets, like 10242 Mini Cooper.

Comment: Yes, I know it is odd and hard to believe, thats why I'm looking for references. I am however certain that I heard a Lego Official say this.

Comment: Can you provide any example countries (especially if this Lego seminar took place in one with such a law)?

Comment: @Chronocidal, no I cannot, I didn't think to ask. The seminar took place in Denmark or Portugal which obviously don't have such laws

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is a partial answer, but an example is quoted in the act to repeal parts of the Californian (USA) slack-fill legislation:

*Toys.  Lego has been sued for slack fill on its "Aqua Zone" building sets.  The boxes which contain the sets are uniform in size, and contain from 29 to 33 pieces, depending on the set.  Each box contains an "actual size" representation of the pieces and a clear and conspicuous disclosure as to the number of pieces.*

From: 
SENATE COMMITTEE ON BUSINESS AND PROFESSIONS
BILL NO:  AB 1394
AUTHOR: Figueroa and Senator Richard G. Polanco, 
Chairman      Escutia
As Amended:  9/4/97
HEARING DATE:  September 5, 1997
FISCAL:  Yes
SUBJECT:  Packaging and Labeling:  expansion of exemptions to slack fill laws.

Comment: Its at least a valuable contribution, it indicates that "slack fill" laws do exist and that it has been an issue with Lego.